# Slack app_home_opened event calling twice

Tags: python, events, slack, slack-api

I have build a slack app.But for onbording process **slack app_home_opened** event calling twice.
I have checked both events are triggered at almost same time.
**Code**

```
from slackeventsapi import SlackEventAdapter

slack_events_adapter = SlackEventAdapter(
    Constants.ENV["SLACK_APP_SIGNING_SECRETS"], "/slack/events", app
)


@slack_events_adapter.on("app_home_opened")
def app_home_opened(event_data):
    threading.Thread(target=handleOnBording).start()
    return "", 200
```

**First event payload:**

```
{
    'token': '*****',
    'team_id': 'T311FQLU8CT',
    'api_app_id': 'K711C41FET3',
    'event': {
        'type': 'app_home_opened',
        'user': 'F511MQLU8KB',
        'channel': 'E211HGWLUKG',
        'tab': 'messages',
        'event_ts': '1590756776.195938'
    },
    'type': 'event_callback',
    'event_id': 'Ev014P7CG7N0',
    'event_time': 1590756776
}
```

**Second event payload:**

```
{
    'token': '*******',
    'team_id': 'T311FQLU8CT',
    'api_app_id': 'K711C41FET3',
    'event': {
        'type': 'app_home_opened',
        'user': 'F511MQLU8KB',
        'channel': 'E211HGWLUKG',
        'tab': 'messages',
        'event_ts': '1590756776.212203'
    },
    'type': 'event_callback',
    'event_id': 'Ev014FLBULHK',
    'event_time': 1590756776
}
```

I am using **slackeventsapi** package of python to interact with slack.I understand slack retries the request if we don't respond in 3 seconds  but i am responding within 3 seconds to every request.

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: updated code as well

Comment: I think we're experiencing the same issue. We've noticed that we usually receive 3 events if we switch between apps (e.g. from Jira -> our app), and 2 events if we switch from direct message/channel to our app. Similarly, we confirmed it's not caused by Slack retrying the request (we respond with 200 immediately, and there's no X-SLACK-RETRY-NUM header on requests).

Answer (score 2):

This might not really be the expected resolution to this issue, but:
I've reached out to the Slack team about this, and it turns out it's a bug, and they are aware of it, though they don't seem to have an ETA on when it's going to be fixed.

With that in mind, I'm afraid if you're experiencing this issue, you should look into implementing a workaround in your events API, that will guarantee you'll only handle one of the events in the series. Depending on your use case and your infrastructure (database, frameworks, etc.), the actual solutions may differ.

Comment: Thanks..we managed  with workaround solution in our events API itself.

Comment: @KamleshKumar what kind of workaround you guys used to make sure event come once only?